# Showing a function source code and asking what it does

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I am a statistics newbie and I have recently ported a function or subroutine in fortran into python. But I have no idea what it does. Is it on topic to ask such questions here ? I am looking to find the equivalent library in python that does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for asking.  This is on the edge.  I, for one, would view it as appropriate for our site assuming the function really is related to stats or machine learning.

Comment: @whuber It is indeed related to stats as it is calculating chi2.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to post your question.  At worst it might collect a few downvotes (depending on the mood of the readers on any particular day...) and get closed, but even then you're likely to get some helpful comments.

Comment: @whuber I posted my question and I deleted. One of the users comments here (Josef) pointed me in the right direction. The getchi2 method that I have corresponds to scipy.stats.ppf. I upvoted his answer and his comment. Do I need to undelete my question as I think it was of poor quality ?

Comment: Asking for code is generally off topic here.  Your question seems like it was borderline.  If you got what you need, I think leaving it deleted is fine.